# Listing specific files matching file type

Tags: bash, find

I am using the find command to search for files in the list of directories stored in array fdir.

```
find "${fdir[@]}" -type f "${sufx[@]}"
```

I amusing `progl=( ".rc" ".el" ".c" ".f")` so I can construct the array `sufx` composed of the expression

```
-name \*.rc -o -name \*.el -o -name \*.c -o -name \*.f
```

How can I do this in a convenient way?

With the grep command, I have just started using

```
sufx+=( --include=\*.{rc,el,c,f} ) 
grep -rl "${sufx[@]}" -e "$phrs" -- "${dra[@]}"
```

One suggested strategy is as follows.  Can the following be improved or simplified?

```
local progl=( ".rc" ".el" ".c" ".f")
local pextd=( "${progl[@]}" ".cp" ".cpp" ".f90" ".f95" ".f03" ".f08")
local typog=( ".org" ".texi" ".tex")

for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do     # include file-type suffixes

  if [[ "$ext" == "progl" ]]; then
    for ft in $progl; do
      sufx+=( -name \*${ft} -o )
    done
    continue
  elif [[ "$ext" == "pextd" ]]; then
    for ft in $pextd; do
      sufx+=( -name \*${ft} -o )
    done
    continue
  elif [[ "$ext" == "typog" ]]; then
    for ft in $typog; do
      sufx+=( -name \*${ft} -o )
    done
    continue  
  fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not as easy to construct a valid argument vector for the `find` command.

Whereas the `grep` command takes single arguments of the form `--include=\*.rc`, to do the (sort of) equivalent in `find` you need to pass two separate arguments `-name` and `*.rc`. To or-chain them, you need a third argument, `-o`

So you could do:

```
args=()

for progl in rc el c f; do
  args+=( -name "*.$progl" -o )
done
```

resulting in

```
$ echo "${args[*]}"
-name *.rc -o -name *.el -o -name *.c -o -name *.f -o
```

There are various ways to deal with the dangling `-o`; for example you can just

```
unset args[-1]
```

or you can chain on a `-false` predicate (since `-o false` is never true). Then you can use the array in a find command like

```
find "${fdir[@]}" -type f \( "${args[@]}" \)
```